# Why glVertexAttribPointer throws 1282 error while trying to draw one point on screen with pyOpenGL and glfw?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, pyopengl

I have separated the program to three different files, but I don't understand why I get error on glVertexAttribPointer on line 70. I'm using Python 3.10.8

main.py

```
import glfw
import Shaders
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from Math_3d import Vector2f


class Window:
    def __init__(self, width: int, height: int, title: str):
        if not glfw.init():
            raise Exception("glfw can not be initialized")
        glfw.window_hint(glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3)
        glfw.window_hint(glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3)
        glfw.window_hint(glfw.OPENGL_PROFILE, glfw.OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE)

        self._win = glfw.create_window(width, height, title, None, None)

        if not self._win:
            glfw.terminate()
            raise Exception("glfw window can not be created")

        glfw.set_window_pos(self._win, 400, 200)
        glfw.make_context_current(self._win)

    def createshaders(self):
        # Request program and shader slots from the GPU
        program = glCreateProgram()
        vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        fragment = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        # Set shader sources
        glShaderSource(vertex, Shaders.vertex_code)
        glShaderSource(fragment, Shaders.fragment_code)
        # Compile shaders
        glCompileShader(vertex)
        glCompileShader(fragment)
        if not glGetShaderiv(vertex, GL_COMPILE_STATUS):
            report_shader = glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex)
            print(report_shader)
            raise RuntimeError("Vertex shader compilation error")

        if not glGetShaderiv(fragment, GL_COMPILE_STATUS):
            report_frag = glGetShaderInfoLog(fragment)
            print(report_frag)
            raise RuntimeError("Fragment shader compilation error")

        # Link objects to program
        glAttachShader(program, vertex)
        glAttachShader(program, fragment)
        glLinkProgram(program)

        if not glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS):
            print(glGetProgramInfoLog(program))
            raise RuntimeError('Linking error')
        # Get rid of shaders
        glDetachShader(program, vertex)
        glDetachShader(program, fragment)
        # Make default program to run
        glUseProgram(program)

        # Vertex Buffer Object
        # Create point vertex data
        v2f_1 = Vector2f(0.0, 0.0)
        # Request a buffer slot from GPU
        buffer = glGenBuffers(1)
        # Make this buffer the default one
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer)
        strides = v2f_1.data.strides[0]
        loc = glGetAttribLocation(program, 'position')
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc)
        glVertexAttribPointer(loc, 2, GL_FLOAT, False, strides, None)
        # glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, v2f_1, v2f_1, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW)

    def renderscene(self):
        while not glfw.window_should_close(self._win):
            glfw.poll_events()
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
            glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1)
            glfw.swap_buffers(self._win)

        glfw.terminate()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = Window(1024, 768, "GLFW Window")
    win.createshaders()  # Create and initialize shaders and initialize Vertex Buffer Object
    win.renderscene()  # Swap buffer and render scene
```

Shaders.py

```
vertex_code = """
    attribute vec2 position;
    void main()
    {
        gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
    }   
    """

fragment_code = """
    void main() 
    { 
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); 
    }
    """
```

Math_3d.py

```
import numpy as np


class Vector2f:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.data = np.array([x, y], dtype=np.float32)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    vec2 = Vector2f(0.0, 0.0)
    print(vec2.data)
    print(type(vec2.data.strides[0]))
    print(vec2.data.strides[0])
```

I have tried to debug the line 70, but did not get any good result while using PyCharm.
Any recommendations on this? Closest answers would be according to 61491497 and 56957118 what I am aiming for.

Comment: Do not apply the suggestions in the answer to the question. This will make the answer useless.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a Core profile [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) (`glfw.OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE`). Therefore you have to create a [Vertex Array Obejct](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object):

```py
class Window:
    # [...]

    def createshaders(self):
        # [...]

        v2f_1 = Vector2f(0.0, 0.0)
        # Request a buffer slot from GPU
        buffer = glGenBuffers(1)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer)
        strides = v2f_1.data.strides[0]
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, v2f_1.data, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW)
        
        vao = glGenVertexArrays(1)
        glBindVertexArray(vao)
        
        loc = glGetAttribLocation(program, 'position')
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc)
        glVertexAttribPointer(loc, 2, GL_FLOAT, False, strides, None)
```

---

Additionally, you need to change either the background color or the fragment color, because you won't be able to see a black point on a black background. e.g. red:

```c
gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```